# Java Comparator type inference confusion

Tags: java, comparator

I have few questions for the following code sample.

```
class HypotheticComparators {
    class Pair<U,T> {
        private U left;
        private T right;
        public U getLeft() {
            return left
        }
        public T getRight() {
            return right;
        }
    }

    class User {
        private String name;
        private Integer age;
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Pair<LocalDate,LocalDate>> dataIntevals = new ArrayList<>();

        //Doesn't Compile
        Comparator<Pair<LocalDate,LocalDate>> pairComparator1  = Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft).thenComparing(Pair::getRight);

        //This Compile
        Comparator<Pair<LocalDate,LocalDate>> leftComparator = Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft);
        Comparator<Pair<LocalDate,LocalDate>> pairComparator2 = leftComparator.thenComparing(Pair::getRight));

        //This compile
        Comparator<User> userComparator1 = Comparator.comparing(User::getName).thenComparing(User::getAge);

        //This also compile
        Comparator<User> userNameComparator = Comparator.comparing(User::getName);
        Comparator<User> userComparator2 = userNameComparator.thenComparing(User::getAge);

    }
}
```

For this statement,         `Comparator<Pair<LocalDate,LocalDate>> pairComparator1  = Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft).thenComparing(Pair::getRight);`,  My initial idea of why it does not compile is that `themComparaing` cannot infer type from  `Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft)`. But i am not convinced by this idea beacuase looking at the source code of `Comparator.comparing` and `thenComparing`

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}

default <U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> thenComparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    return thenComparing(comparing(keyExtractor));
}
```

`Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft)` can have type inference with T as `Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>` , `themComparing` can also have a type inference with T as `Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>`. Furthermore, if my idea is correct, why         `Comparator<User> userNameComparator = Comparator.comparing(User::getName);` can compile without any problem. Am i missing anything here ?

Answer (score 2):

The Java type-inferer can't be sure that the first `.comparing` is going to be accepting the same type that the second one is, so it guesses that the types for the first method are `Object, Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>`, and Object doesn't implement Comparable. You can work around this by specifying the generic types for the method:

```
Comparator<Pair<LocalDate,LocalDate>> pairComparator1  = Comparator
    .<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>, LocalDate>comparing(Pair::getLeft)
    .thenComparing(Pair::getRight);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the compiler can't infer the type of `Pair::getLeft` in the first case, but can in the second case, is because it uses the type of the variable to infer the type, but because you call `thenComparing()` right away, it doesn't have access to this information.

You can check this by having `Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft);` by itself on a new line, without saving it to a variable. The compiler will fail to infer the type.

This can be resolved by explicitly saying `Pair<LocalDate,LocalDate>::getLeft`.